# Factoring large integers with the Pollard p-1 method

Tags: number-theory, factorization

I am trying to use the Pollard $p-1$ method to find the factors of a large integer. Here is the problem:

> An RSA-type cipher is based on the integer $n = 140016480344628383$
>   and exponent $2345671$. Factor n into a product of two primes, $p$ and $q$, using the Pollard $p-1$ method with base 2.
>
> Once you have found $p$ and $q$, find the decryption index $d$ satisfying 
>   $de \equiv1\, ({\rm mod}\,(p-1)(q-1))$

None of my code is working. I can't seem to get it setup without having an overflow. Any tips and pointers would be so appreciated!

Here was one of my code attempts:

```
n = 140016480344628383;
b = 2;
y = 0;
z = 0;
ls = {};
p = 0;
For[k = 0, k <= 1500, k++,
  y = Mod[b^k!, n];
  b^k != Mod[y*(y - 1), n];
  z = y - 1;
  p = GCD[z, n];
  If[GCD[z, n] > 1, ls = Append[ls, p]];
];
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Please add your code to the question, so that readers can help you with it.

Comment: Per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_p_%E2%88%92_1_algorithm): `In[109]:= n = 140016480344628383;
b = 2000;
mbig = Product[Prime[j]^Floor[Log[Prime[j], b]], {j, PrimePi[b]}];
g = PowerMod[2, mbig, n];
GCD[g - 1, n]

Out[113]= 373607131`

Answer (score 4):

Essentially all you need to get your code to terminate is

- Convert `Mod[b^k!, n]` to `PowerMod[b, k!, n]` (`b^k!` caused the overflow).
- Break out of your loop once `p` has been found.

Here's your code with these slight modifications. (I also added `Monitor` to see the progress.)

```
n = 140016480344628383;
b = 2;
y = 0;
z = 0;
p = 0;

Monitor[
  For[k = 0, k <= 15000, k++,
    y = PowerMod[b, k!, n];
    z = y - 1;
    p = GCD[z, n];
    If[p > 1, Return[p]];
  ], k
]
```

> ```
>  373607131
> ```

Finally we can verify to make sure everything went smoothly.

```
FactorInteger[140016480344628383]
```

> ```
> {{373607131, 1}, {374769293, 1}}
> ```

**Edit:** I think there still might be a problem in your code. What is the line

```
b^k != Mod[y*(y - 1), n];
```

supposed to do? The way you have it, whether it's `True` or `False`, it doesn't effect evaluation.

**Edit 2:** I have removed that line from the code after getting clarification in the comments section.

Comment: Wow, thank you SO much! You have saved me hours of staring at my computer. Thank you.

Comment: @Nora see my edit, what is `b^k != Mod[y*(y - 1), n];` supposed to do?

Comment: Here is my now updated code: e = 2345671;
n = 140016480344628383; b = 2; y = 0; z = 0; p = 0; Monitor[
 For[k = 0, k <= 15000, k++,
  y = PowerMod[b, k!, n]; b^k = Mod[y*(y - 1), n]; z = y - 1; 
  p = GCD[z, n]; If[GCD[z, n] > 1, Return[p]];], k]

Comment: @Nora I'm still confused. You can't assign `b^k` a value. Can you say in words what that line is supposed to do?

Comment: The b^k != Mod[y*(y - 1), n]; is my attempt at computing b^(k+1)! without overflow. 
where b is 2 and k is the iterations.
That line is now not even needed in the code.
It now works correctly and I was able to verify it with the FactorInteger command!

Comment: @Nora Ok, in that case I think you should just remove that line from your code. It serves no purpose.

Comment: Exactly! It has been removed. 
I am about to post another Mathematica question, feel free to chime in again!

Comment: @nora if the answer did help you I'd suggest you upvote it.